# Apache Toree - How to connect Spark Kernel Service with Client code?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-toree

I'm trying to build a Java/Scala application that will submit spark code to a remote spark cluster. I am using Apache Toree i.e. Spark Kernal to achieve this. I have successfully connected and started the Apache Toree service with Spark on YARN.

I need to write a Java/Scala client to connect to this running Apache Toree service so as to interactive submit spark code.

To write a client I'm referring to the following examples in the project

https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree/blob/master/client/src/test/scala/examples/DocumentationExamples.scala

Now my question is - if the Spark Kernel/Apache Toree is running on one of the edge nodes having an ip address 10.22.34.10:8042 or http://example.com:8042 where do I specify this address in the client code so that the client code makes a connect with the remote Spark Kernel/Apache Toree service and submits the spark code to the running Spark Kernel for execution?

In a nutshell - How do we establish a connect between a client and the Apache Toree service/Spark Kernel i.e. I mean how does the client know where to submit the spark code? - I'm unable to find the configuration in the sample example (link above).

PS: I'm not using Jupyter at any place in my use case - simple running Toree service on Spark-Yarn and writing a client in Java/scala to submit/execute Spark code.

Please let me know if i'm missing on something important as a configuration for my use-case.

A link/sample to a working Java/Scala sample code to connect to the running Toree service which can submit and execute the spark code will be highly appreciated. Thank you!